# display all customers using console command magento2.2.3

Tags: magento2.2.3, cli

How to display registered customers in terminal using custom console command?Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to create `di.xml` in your customer module(I am assuming that you already know how to create a module)

`app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="registered_customer_list" xsi:type="object">VENDOR\MODULE\Console\Command\GetRegisteredCustomerList</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>    
</config>
```

Now you need to create `GetRegisteredCustomerList.php`

`app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Console/Command/GetRegisteredCustomerList.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MODULE\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory;


class GetRegisteredCustomerList extends Command
{
    const COMMAND = 'customer:list';


    private $customerCollectionFactory;


    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName(self::COMMAND);
        $desc = 'Registered customers list';
        $this->setDescription($desc);
    }


    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        try {
            $table = $this->getHelperSet()->get('table');
            $table->setHeaders(['ID', 'Website ID', 'Group ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email']);

            $customerCollection = $this->customerCollectionFactory->create();
            foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
                $table->addRow([
                    $customer->getData('entity_id'),
                    $customer->getData('website_id'),
                    $customer->getData('group_id'),
                    $customer->getData('firstname'),
                    $customer->getData('lastname'),
                    $customer->getData('email'),
                ]);
            }

            $table->render($output);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $output->writeln("<error>Error executing command: {$e->getMessage()}</error>");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to execute the `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command from the magento root directory

and `php bin/magento cache:clean`

And now you can get your registered customer list by executing below command,

`php bin/magento customer:list`

it will print something like this,

```
$ php bin/magento customer:list
+----+------------+----------+------------+-----------+------------------------------+
| ID | Website ID | Group ID | First Name | Last Name | Email                        |
+----+------------+----------+------------+-----------+------------------------------+
| 1  | 1          | 1        | Keyur      | Shah1     | keyurtest@gmail.com   |
| 2  | 1          | 1        | Keyur      | Shah      | keyur@gmail.com              |
| 3  | 1          | 1        | Keyur      | Shah      | keyurdemo@gmail.com  |
| 4  | 1          | 1        | Keyur      | Shah      | demo@gmail.com |
| 5  | 1          | 1        | Keyur      | Shah      | test@gmail.com    |
+----+------------+----------+------------+-----------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add your own commands for listing customers:

add your command class through di.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customersList" xsi:type="object">Comapany\ModuleName\Console\Command\CustomersList</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Create your class. Take help from magento created command classes. Here i create class from Magento\Catalog\Console\Command\ProductAttributesCleanUp

```
<?php

namespace Comapany\ModuleName\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

/**
 * Class ProductAttributesCleanUp
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CustomersList extends \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command
{

     /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     */
    protected $appState;

    /**
     * @var  \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $customerCollectionFactory;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory

    ) {
        $this->appState = $appState;
        $this->customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('customers:list');
        $this->setDescription('List All Customers.');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->setDecorated(true);
        $this->appState->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);


        $output->writeln("");
        $collection =$this->customerCollectionFactory->create();
        $output->writeln("<info>Customers:</info>");
        foreach ($collection as $customer) {
            $output->writeln("<comment> ".$customer->getEmail()." </comment>");
        }


        return \Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_SUCCESS;

    }


}
```

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "customers" namespace.     
                                                                  
  Did you mean one of these?                                      
      customer                                                    
      customer:hash

Comment: missed to update the name of command ,now updated my post name="customersList" .
after making changes run setup:upgrade and cache:flush command

Comment: yes, check the updated post, it will display the email of all customers . you can update it according to your need.

Comment: Argument 2 passed to Codem\Timeslot\Console\Command\CustomersList::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory, none given, called in /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 and defined in /Library/WebServer/Documents/magento/app/code/Codem/Timeslot/Console/Command/CustomersList.php on line 30...This error appears

Comment: clean your generated directory and try cache flush

Comment: okay..Should I delete the contents in generated directory?How can I perform clean ?

Comment: yes delete the content of generated directory

Comment: After deleting generated folder,It worked.It displayed all customers.@satya prakash patel.Thanks so much.How can I get other attributes?

Comment: you can use getAttributename() e.g. $customer->getFirstname() , $customer->getLastname()

Comment: Similarly,How can I get order details?

Comment: you can use \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory as we used for customers